# Postgres function must have return type record because of OUT parameters

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql

I have written the following function in postgresql and am facing the below mentioned error. Can anyone help me how to fix it?

> ERROR:  function result type must be record because of OUT parameters
>   SQL state: 42P13

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION fun_audit_trail(in as_on_date date, out mail_id varchar, out user_id varchar, out user_name varchar, 
        out last_login_time timestamp, out last_logout_time timestamp, out logout_flag varchar, out user_available_flag varchar)
  RETURNS setof ret_cursor AS 
$BODY$

DECLARE ref_cursor ret_cursor;

BEGIN

    open ref_cursor for 
    select am.am_usrmailid,am.am_usr_loginid,am.am_usr_name,am.am_last_login_time,am.am_last_logout_time,am.am_logout_flag,am.am_usr_available_flag 
    into mail_id,user_id,user_name,last_login_time,last_logout_time,logout_flag,user_available_flag
    from auth_monitor am where am_last_login_time <= as_on_date
    return next ref_cursor;

END $BODY$
  LANGUAGE 'plpgsql' COST 100.0 SECURITY INVOKER
```

Comment: `returns setof reF_cursor` not `returns setof reT_cursor`

Answer (score 2):

Why use a refcursor at all? And `returns setof ref_cursor` means you want to return more than one refcursor which you clearly don't want to do.

A `language sql` function declared as `returns table()` is the correct choice if you want to return a result from a function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION fun_audit_trail(in as_on_date date)
  RETURNS table(mail_id varchar, user_id varchar, user_name varchar, 
                last_login_time timestamp, last_logout_time timestamp, 
                logout_flag varchar, user_available_flag varchar)
$BODY$
    select am.am_usrmailid,am.am_usr_loginid,am.am_usr_name,am.am_last_login_time,am.am_last_logout_time,am.am_logout_flag,am.am_usr_available_flag 
    from auth_monitor am 
    where am_last_login_time <= as_on_date
$BODY$
LANGUAGE sql;
```

Then you can use it like this:

```
select *
from fun_audit_trail(date '2019-10-20');
```

Comment: @abraham: Postgres functions aren't really meant to return more than one result set. Anything you can achieve with `returns setof ref_cursor` will be extremely inconvenient to use. You should seriously consider to provide one function for each result instead. Postgres isn't SQL Server and "coding patterns" that work with SQL Server, usually don't fit into the way things are done in Postgres.

Comment: Thanks, Is there any possibility to return more than one result set in postgres functions? Because its not allows stored procedures.

Comment: There are some really ugly ways using ref cursor, but as I already mentioned: using them will be extremely complicated (and that is the same for stored procedures - they aren't meant to return anything to begin with)